# Composer: Version conflicts in circular dependency

Tags: php, composer-php

First of all, I know this setup is stupid but this is what we're stuck with ‍♂️

We build websites with our company framework. The website contains some classes that the framework directly accesses. This means we have a circular dependency. This was not a problem until now.

These are slimmer versions of our `composer.json`s:

**Framework**:

The framework just defines some other

```
{
    "name": "company/framework",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Website**:

```
{
    "name": "company/website",
    "require": {
        "company/framework": "^4.3",
        ...
    }
}
```

Very simple, `framework` is a dependency of `website`.

Now, I'm trying to setup a CI server with static analysis for the `framework`. As mentioned, the `framework` requires some files in the `website` for static analysis to succeed.

The new **company/framework/composer.json** file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "company/framework",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        "company/website": "^4.3",
        ...
    }
}
```

This works fine when testing a tagged `framework` version. Whenever we're in a develop branch Composer will fail since `website` requires a stable `^4.3` version of the framework but this is a develop branch.

Is there any way I can work around this?

Comment: I hope the question is understandable. If anything isn't clear, please ask!

Comment: @PaulCrovella Thanks for the link, but I'm not entirely sure how this would help me.

Comment: I don't get the question. Can you clarify the problem? Why don't you just install what is needed? Is the problem about the framework being installed from a tagged version or the master branch? That might be solved through `minimum-stability`?

Comment: The problem effectively comes from `website` requesting a version of `framework` that is stable. But when the CI runs on a feature branch the `framework` is not stable. Maybe the branch aliases could help after all, I'm gonna try a few different things.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the classes that are needed to test the framework into a separate package.

Framework requires that package.

Website requires that package. And requires Framework (which also requires that package).

Voila, you transformed a circular dependency into a linear graph.

Add semantic versioning to this approach, and you will never have serious problems - or spot them pretty soon.

Comment: Yeah believe me I would if I could... Unfortunately this is not an option. These classes are in the website to be extended. Of course I could extract it just for the skeleton but then the skeleton would be different than the dozens of actual websites. And you'd have to fix this each time forking the skeleton.

Comment: Can you add more repos to your source code management? If you cannot, that would be a nasty, but valid reason. The argument you have however does not sound convincing to me at the moment. Can you describe the situation with the class usage a bit more in detail (edit/append to your question above, please).